# Value error in numpy random code

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying make a code that gets the probability of getting numbers between 0.5 and 0.6 in the interval 0 to 1.

```
from numpy import *        
import sys        
N = int(sys.argv[1])        
r = random.uniform(0, 1, N)        
M = sum(0.5 <= r, r <= 0.6)        
p= float(M)/N         
print p        

    M = sum(0.5 <= r >= 0.6)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When i try to run this, i get this valueerror. What is wrong, and what should i do to fix it?

Comment: You have two different versions of the `M` assignment here.

Answer (score -2):

```
import system.*        
N = int(system.args[1])        
r = random.uniform(0, 1, N)        
M = sum(0.5 <= r, r <= 0.6)        
p= float(M)/N         
print p        

    M = sum(0.5 <= r >= 0.6)
```

Comment: This is *wronger* than the original code.